# How to use a specific port while Testing web service clients

Tags: scalatest, playframework-2.5

Im following the play framework 2.5 documentation to write tests using web service clients

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWebServiceClients

The code below is extracted from above link which works. However as mentioned in the documentation, a random available port is assigned when using **implicit** port.

Is it possible to give a specific port instead of random port?

```
 import play.core.server.Server
 object GitHubClientSpec extends Specification with NoTimeConversions {
      "GitHubClient" should {
           "get all repositories" in {
                Server.withRouter() {
                     case GET(p"/repositories") => Action {
                          Results.Ok(Json.arr(Json.obj("full_name" ->
                                                       "octocat/HelloWorld")))
                   }
       } { implicit port =>
                  WsTestClient.withClient { client =>
                  val result = Await.result(
                  new GitHubClient(client, "").repositories(), 10.seconds)
                  result must_== Seq("octocat/Hello-World")
             }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to get into the definition of `withRouter`, you'll see it takes `ServerConfig` in which you can provide the `port` and `run mode`.

```
 import play.core.server.Server
 object GitHubClientSpec extends Specification with NoTimeConversions {
  "GitHubClient" should {
       "get all repositories" in {
            //here 8888 is the port which you have defined.
            Server.withRouter(ServerConfig(port = Some(8888), mode = Mode.Test)) {
                 case GET(p"/repositories") => Action {
                      Results.Ok(Json.arr(Json.obj("full_name" ->
                                                   "octocat/HelloWorld")))
               }
   } { implicit port =>
              //The port will 8888 in this block
              WsTestClient.withClient { client =>
              val result = Await.result(
              new GitHubClient(client, "").repositories(), 10.seconds)
              result must_== Seq("octocat/Hello-World")
         }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps, happy coding :)

Comment: How do I import Mode? Also whats Mode.Test means?

I have used ServerConfig without mode and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: You can use MODE by `import play.api.Mode` , this actually sets the mode of you current application eg. test, prod, dev.
and yes you can ignore mode for your current case it won't give any error because it has default value.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to build.sbt worked

```
 PlayKeys.devSettings := Seq("play.server.http.port" -> "9100")
```